# My Pi getting heated for no reason. How do I debug?

Tags: raspbian, hardware, power-supply, monitoring

I wrote the Wheezy image, booted with rPi, expanded size, rebooted. Then I played couple of games, Python Games. Then I opened the default browser, however it was slow. I only opened two pages, one with Google.com and another eLinux. The browser tab would stop responding and then again would load. Then I touched the rPi and I felt it was warm.

Then I rebooted it, removed everything and now running it as headless device. I installed RPi Monitor and here are the stats. Nothing is connected other than ethernet cable. I am using Apple's iPhone 4 charger which is 5V/1A.

The CPU temp is 60°C, is that normal? I have kept my rPi in one of those acrylic cases and I can feel hot when I touch it.

[image]

[image]

here is output of `ps aux`:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.1  0.1   2144   744 ?        Ss   18:55   0:01 init [2]  
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [kworker/u2:0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [rcu_preempt]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [rcu_sched]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [khelper]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [netns]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [kworker/0:1]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [writeback]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [bioset]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [kblockd]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [khubd]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [rpciod]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [nfsiod]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [crypto]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [VCHIQ-0]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [VCHIQr-0]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [VCHIQs-0]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [iscsi_eh]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [dwc_otg]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [DWC Notificatio]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [deferwq]
root        39  0.8  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:11 [mmcqd/0]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [jbd2/mmcblk0p2-]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:55   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       156  0.0  0.2   2884  1272 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       280  0.0  0.2   2880   996 ?        S    18:55   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       281  0.0  0.2   2880   996 ?        S    18:55   0:00 udevd --daemon
root      1523  0.0  0.1   1748   552 ?        S    18:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i eth0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      1556  0.0  0.1   1748   544 ?        S    18:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i lo -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      1686  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:55   0:00 [kworker/0:2]
root      1814  0.0  0.4   4896  1992 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 dhclient -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhcli
root      1851  0.0  0.3  27972  1540 ?        Sl   18:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
nobody    1860  0.0  0.1   2016   636 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/thd --daemon --triggers /etc/triggerhappy/triggers.d
root      1916  0.0  0.2   3824   976 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
104       1924  0.0  0.2   3316  1236 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
root      1979  0.0  0.6  30696  3024 ?        Sl   18:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/lightdm
root      1992  0.1  1.6  13212  7288 tty7     Ss+  18:55   0:01 /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7
ntp       2012  0.0  0.3   5512  1700 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 102:104
root      2051  0.0  0.2   6212  1072 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      2073  0.0  0.6  15996  3108 ?        Sl   18:55   0:00 lightdm --session-child 12 15
root      2084  0.0  0.1   3744   804 tty1     Ss+  18:55   0:00 /sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1
root      2085  0.0  0.1   3744   804 tty2     Ss+  18:55   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty2
root      2086  0.0  0.1   3744   804 tty3     Ss+  18:55   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty3
root      2087  0.0  0.1   3744   804 tty4     Ss+  18:55   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty4
root      2088  0.0  0.1   3744   804 tty5     Ss+  18:55   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty5
root      2089  0.0  0.1   3744   804 tty6     Ss+  18:55   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty6
root      2090  0.0  0.1   2064   732 ?        Ss+  18:55   0:00 /sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
root      2092  0.0  0.8  27540  3720 ?        Sl   18:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
root      2159  0.0  0.6  22288  3032 ?        Sl   18:55   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
pi        2171  0.0  0.3  12796  1504 ?        Ssl  18:56   0:00 /usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE -e LXDE
pi        2181  0.0  0.0   3524   352 ?        Ss   18:56   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session x-
pi        2184  0.0  0.1   3372   712 ?        S    18:56   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session x-session-manager
pi        2185  0.0  0.2   3308   964 ?        Ss   18:56   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --
pi        2191  0.0  1.3  14820  6100 ?        S    18:56   0:00 openbox --config-file /home/pi/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
pi        2193  0.2  1.8 104772  8104 ?        S    18:56   0:03 lxpanel --profile LXDE
pi        2194  0.1  2.4 124488 10768 ?        S    18:56   0:01 pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
pi        2197  0.0  1.0  26656  4508 ?        Sl   18:56   0:00 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxpolkit
pi        2200  0.0  0.5   6456  2352 ?        S    18:56   0:00 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmenu-cache1/libexec/menu-cache
pi        2203  0.0  0.4   8548  2216 ?        S    18:56   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
pi        2211  0.0  0.7   9292  3208 ?        S    18:56   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor
root      2213  0.0  0.7  14536  3192 ?        Sl   18:56   0:00 /usr/lib/udisks/udisks-daemon
root      2214  0.0  0.1   6188   796 ?        S    18:56   0:00 udisks-daemon: not polling any devices
pi        2217  0.0  0.5   8916  2272 ?        S    18:56   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
pi        2219  0.0  0.5  19136  2296 ?        Sl   18:56   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
root      2221  0.0  0.6   9256  2908 ?        Ss   18:56   0:00 sshd: pi [priv]  
pi        2225  0.0  0.3   9256  1472 ?        S    18:56   0:00 sshd: pi@pts/0  
pi        2226  0.1  0.7   6256  3504 pts/0    Ss   18:56   0:02 -bash
root      5127  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    19:00   0:00 [kworker/u2:1]
root      5204  0.0  1.4  19676  6592 ?        SNs  19:05   0:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/rpimonitord -b /var/run/rpimonitord.pid
pi        5228  0.2  1.6  19984  7552 ?        SN   19:05   0:02 /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/rpimonitord -b /var/run/rpimonitord.pid
root      5229  0.9  1.5  19676  6844 ?        SN   19:05   0:07 /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/rpimonitord -b /var/run/rpimonitord.pid
root      5232  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    19:05   0:00 [VCHIQka-0]
pi        6219  0.0  0.2   4456  1128 pts/0    R+   19:17   0:00 ps aux
```

and when I run the commands form terminal:

```
pi@raspi ~ $ /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
temp=60.5'C
pi@raspi ~ $ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
59990
```

Even GPU is at 60°C! btw I don't know room temperature, however Accu whether says 40°C for my location.

Comment: My temperature is shown as 44 degrees C.  About 20 degrees over ambient.  Pretty much the same as yours.

Comment: Yeah, my Pis always heat up quite a bit. If you're really worried about it might install one of this tiny VRAM heatsinks to help dissipate heat. An open case, good ventilation, etc, would probably help. Keep in mind as well that while 60C seems warm, in the realm of computing that's not actually too, too bad.

Comment: FYI: I found that putting a heatsink on, one of those with the tape on it, makes it even worse. So if you thinking of that then dont do it. It seems the chip design on its own is much better, unless you put a fan on it? Mini fan? But even without heatsink a fan would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for the CPU to be 10 to 20 degrees warmer than its surroundings.

60 is a bit warm so try removing the case to give it better ventilation, and put it in a cool dry place (not in the sun, etc).

As long as you keep it under 85 degrees (and have not over volted), your warranty is OK.

```
(force_turbo || current_limit_override || temp_limit>85) && over_voltage>0
```